# Join XML data from different elements using Transact-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery

I'm trying to combine info from different nodes using the OPENXML function. For example, using the following xml data I would like to fill in as much data as possible and join based on the 'PartyId' so I can get the 'PartyRoleCode' from 'MoreInfo':

```
 <Root>
   <Parties>
      <Party PartyId="Party_1">
         <PartyTypeCode PartyTypeCode="Bastard"></PartyTypeCode>
         <PersonInfo>
            <FirstName>Jon</FirstName>
            <LastName>Snow</LastName>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
         </PersonInfo>
         <EmailAddress>knowsnothing@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
      </Party>
      <Party PartyId="Party_2">
         <PartyTypeCode PartyTypeCode="Stark"></PartyTypeCode>
         <PersonInfo>
            <FirstName>Eddard</FirstName>
            <LastName>Stark</LastName>
         </PersonInfo>
      </Party>
   </Parties>
     <MoreInfo>
         <Parties>
            <PartyRef PartyId="Party_1">
               <PartyRole PartyRoleCode="Nights Watch"></PartyRole>
            </PartyRef>
            <PartyRef PartyId="Party_1">
               <PartyRole PartyRoleCode="Wildling"></PartyRole>
            </PartyRef>
            <PartyRef PartyId="Party_2">
               <PartyRole PartyRoleCode="Kings Hand"></PartyRole>
            </PartyRef>
         </Parties>
   </MoreInfo>
</Root>
```

How could I output the following:

```
PartyRolecode   FirstName   LastName   Gender   Email Address
-------------   ---------   --------   ------   -------------
Nights Watch    Jon         Snow       M        knowsnothing@gmail.com
Wildling        Jon         Snow       M        knowsnothing@gmail.com
Kings Hand      Eddard      Stark
```

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Root>
   <Parties>
      <Party PartyId="Party_1">
         <PartyTypeCode PartyTypeCode="Bastard"></PartyTypeCode>
         <PersonInfo>
            <FirstName>Jon</FirstName>
            <LastName>Snow</LastName>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
         </PersonInfo>
         <EmailAddress>knowsnothing@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
      </Party>
      <Party PartyId="Party_2">
         <PartyTypeCode PartyTypeCode="Stark"></PartyTypeCode>
         <PersonInfo>
            <FirstName>Eddard</FirstName>
            <LastName>Stark</LastName>
         </PersonInfo>
      </Party>
   </Parties>
     <MoreInfo>
         <Parties>
            <PartyRef PartyId="Party_1">
               <PartyRole PartyRoleCode="Nights Watch"></PartyRole>
            </PartyRef>
            <PartyRef PartyId="Party_1">
               <PartyRole PartyRoleCode="Wildling"></PartyRole>
            </PartyRef>
            <PartyRef PartyId="Party_2">
               <PartyRole PartyRoleCode="Kings Hand"></PartyRole>
            </PartyRef>
         </Parties>
   </MoreInfo>
</Root>';
```

--The query will read all `<Party>` elements, use `APPLY` to read the `@PartyId` and use another `APPLY` to read related `<PartyRef>` elements using the `@PartyId` as a result set's column with `sql:column()`:

```
SELECT B.PartyID
      ,pr.value(N'(PartyRole/@PartyRoleCode)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS PartyRoleCode
      ,p.value(N'(PersonInfo/FirstName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS FirstName
      ,p.value(N'(PersonInfo/LastName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS LastName
      ,p.value(N'(PersonInfo/Gender/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Gender
      ,p.value(N'(EmailAddress/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS eMail
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Root/Parties/Party') AS A(p)
OUTER APPLY(SELECT p.value(N'@PartyId','nvarchar(max)') AS PartyID) AS B
OUTER APPLY @xml.nodes(N'Root/MoreInfo/Parties/PartyRef[@PartyId=sql:column("B.PartyID")]') AS C(pr);
```

Comment: I realized it was a problem with the data itself, thanks for all your help!